# Is there any module to provide "more like this"?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, morelikethis

I'm looking for a module (or a way) which can provide the 'more like this' block in drupal without using the apache solr module.

Comment: http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/

Comment: Thank you but i want something similar without lucene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used it myself but this should do what you want - http://drupal.org/project/morelikethis

As you're in Drupal 7 you could do this using taxonomy and Views - http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-related-content-view-drupal-7

Comment: Thank you very much but it seemed that i forgot to notice that i'm working on drupal7 ..

Comment: Ah sorry. 2nd time today I've done that. I've adjusted the answer. It's not a module but will work.

Comment: But I'm sure i saw a module that can do it without views or anything but unfortunatley i lost its name

Comment: Probably but Views is awesome. You could do a lot worse than using it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this module [Relevent content](http://drupal.org/project/relevant_content) that it makes the same thing, it provides similar content based on taxonomy .
Welcome and thank you